# Proof about lognormal distribution

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm trying to prove a result about the lognormal distribution that seems to me to be fairly intuitive, but I can't get the proof to work. Basically, I'd like to prove that as the mean increases, the expected value below a certain threshold (say $x^*$) increases more by raising the variance than by lowering the mean.

Formally, let

$V = \int_0^{x^*} x f(x) dx$,

where $f(x)$ is the lognormal pdf with mean $y-a$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I'd like to show

$\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial y \partial a} < \frac{\partial^2V}{\partial y \partial \sigma}$

I'd really appreciate any help.